# Syntax for calling Excel COM (actxserver) methods in Matlab - Specifically the 'Find' method

Tags: excel, matlab, methods, com

I have search and search and just can't seem to figure this out. I think this is a pretty general question applicable to a lot of methods, but mine is specifically for 'Find'.

I am data mining AND writing to an Excel spreadsheet in the Matlab environment.  I have been able to do quite a bit but I've been using a work around for something I can't figure out for over a year and it really slows things down.

I need to call the 'Find' method to look for specific values of cells.

Here is where I'm at...
    Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
    Sheet = Excel.Worksheets.Item(mysheet);
    Sheet.Activate;
    cellObj = Sheet.Cells;

Now... here is what I need to do.  I want to find a cell that contains EXACTLY the value 'myData_1'.  So I try to use...

```
cellObj.Find('myData_1')
```

of course

```
invoke(cellObj,'Find','myData_1')
```

also works..

Either way the call does find a cell, but the cell actually contains 'myData_10'. Since the default 'Find' method parameters in Excel are only for a partial match.

So I recorded a macro and discovered that there is a 'Find' property called 'LookAt: = xlPart'.  Also I discovered that if I set that property to 'xlWhole' it will be an Exact match per the Microsoft Developer website.

Now, back to the Matlab environment. According to cellObj.methodsview, I should be able to call 'Find' with (handle,Variant,Variant(Optional))...

So, I tried...

```
invoke(cellObj,'Find','myData_1','LookAt:=xlWhole').
```

I also tried about 50 other combinations of syntax as well.  I just CAN NOT figure out what the proper syntax is to search for the cell value I want AND change the 'LookAt' property.

Can anyone please help me?  And please, to make this thread productive, do not ask why I am doing anything with Excel, there is a very good reason for my work to be done this way.

Thanks in advance,
Justin

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use `cellobj.Find('myData_1',[],[],1)` it should do what you need.

If you take a look at the [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for `Range.Find` you'll see that the `LookAt` parameter is the fourth, so I've put empty arrays to leave the second and third arguments as default. The constant 1 corresponds to `xlWhole`, 2 corresponds to `xlPart`. (I guessed that and it worked - I've never been sure how to work out what numbers the enumerated constants in Excel correspond to, but often they are an initial set of integers).

Hope that helps!